# JSON POST requests empty response on Node/Mongo

Tags: node.js, json, post, mongoose

Edit: I solved it. It was pretty simple, I had imported the routes before setting app.use for body-parser, so it didn't knew hot to parse JSON and thus returned an undefined body.

I'm trying to make a REST API following a tutorial. I made everything exactly as it was done in it, and tried every fix I could think of, but I can't make JSON POST requests work.
After sending a request I'm supposed to get a JSON like this:

```json
{
  "_id": "a13d1s2bc12as3a2",
  "name": "Name",
  "desc": "bla bla",
  "_v": 0
}
```

But instead I'm only getting a 201 Resource with an empty body. Not even an empty object, just nothing.

- I tried all the possible configurations in Postman and also HTTPie.
- I also tried the suggested fixes changing body-parser config, since I got a clue something was deprecated or changed in the last months (json, urlencoded, etc.)
- I checked if Mongoose was connected to the DB using the function it has for checking it (it was).

I have no clue where's the problem.

This is the index:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const meals = require("./routes/meals");
const orders = require("./routes/orders");
const app = express();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.use("/meals", meals);
app.use("/orders", orders);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));

module.exports = app;
```

The routes for Meals:

```
const express = require("express");
const Meals = require("../models/Meals");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Meals.find()
    .exec()
    .then(x => res.status(200).send(x));
});

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    Meals.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then(x => res.status(200).send(x));

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    Meals.create(req.body)
    .then(x => res.status(201).send(x));
});

router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
    Meals.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
    .then(x => res.sendStatus(204));
});

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
    Meals.findOneAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(204));
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Meals = mongoose.model("Meal", new Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: String
 }));

 module.exports = Meals;
```

Thank you.

Comment: as you said you are getting 201 response, which may is returned by this line `.then(x => res.status(201).send(x));` in your above code, `Meals.create(req.body)` ,  you may have to first debug if you are able to connect and  if  Meals.create is working

Comment: I checked using the "isConnected()" and "on error" methods and it said it was connected. Is there any other way to debug it?

Comment: I posted an example of error handler

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. Routes and model were fine, I had imported the routes before importing body-parser, so it didn't know how to parse JSON and thus returned undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To debug try this

```
const handleError = function() {
    console.error(err);
    // handle your error
};

router.post("/", (req, res) => {

  Meals.create(req.body, function (err, req.body) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
  })

});
```

You can also try to just provide static data for testing and see if that works, like :

```
const meal = new Meals({ name: 'some meal',desc: 'some desc' });
meal.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved! return 200 or whatever you needs to do here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was pretty simple, I had imported the routes before setting app.use for body-parser, so it didn't knew hot to parse JSON and thus returned an undefined body.

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/meals", meals);
app.use("/orders", orders);

module.exports = app;
```